# wordpress - Make plugin options available in front-end for registered users

Tags: wordpress, plugins, frontend

I have tried to search but i was unable to find or i used the wrong keywords for that.

Here's my Question:

Is there a way to make the backend option of a wordpress plugin to be available in the front-end site so the users don't have to go to wp-admin to add/change things.
The plugin in question is http://wordpress.org/plugins/gw2-chars/, I was able to change the permission to allow the registered uses to see it on the back-end (instead of the default that just allowed for editor or above to use it).

Any help would be great appreciated.

Thanks